# Adding libraries to Google App Engine Projects

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've been trying to add [Markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) library to my GAE app but it keeps throwing an ImportError. This is what I have:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib\markdown2")
```

if I now do

```
html = markdown2.markdown("*boo*") #throws an error: markdown2 not defined
```

Comment: Is that really a backslash? Or is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `lib` directory to your path, not the `markdown` directory - markdown is a package, defined by the directory it's in.

This should work:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

Comment: Hey Nick. Thanks for the answer. I've made the change. Do I need to add an `import` statement as well to make this work or this is the only line which is required. I tried both ways and I am still getting the same error: `markdown2` is not defined. And when I write an import statement(along with the `sys.path.append`) I get an import error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have this query - do I need to use the entire library folder as it is or I can just use the `markdown2.py` file (in which case its working fine). I'm new to python and I have no idea what each folder in the library is for. Should I include everything or just one specific file? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Prakhar I'm not familiar with Markdown in particular. In general, if the directory has an `__init__.py` file, it's a package and you should include it. It sounds like markdown is just a module, in which case you can include it straight in your root directory, no need for path manipulations. And yes, you always need the import statement - the `sys.path` manipulation is just to make sure Python can find the module.

Answer (score 1):

I use markdown2 with a simple import :

```
import lib.markdown
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the library uses relative imports anywhere - and it's generally a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's one of the standard libraries.
You'll need to include a copy of it inside your app folder - otherwise it won't be available when you deploy.

You shouldn't need to modify the path after that just import it with the correct path relative to your app's root folder.

for example:

if your app is at
    /home/myapp

you might want to copy your markdown2 to
    /home/myapp/lib/markdown2

in which case you'd use "import lib.markdown2".